# Java JodaTime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/Chronology

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I am writing a basic Java program using JodaTime to convert a date from the Gregorian Calendar to the Islamic Hijri Calendar. However, when I run my code, I get the following error:

> Error: Unable to initialize main class MainActivity Caused by:
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/Chronology

Below is my code:

```
import org.joda.time.Chronology;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.chrono.IslamicChronology;
import org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology;

public class MainActivity {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chronology iso = ISOChronology.getInstanceUTC();
        Chronology hijri = IslamicChronology.getInstanceUTC();

        LocalDate todayIso = new LocalDate(2021, 8, 17, iso);
        LocalDate todayHijri = new LocalDate(todayIso.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(),
                           hijri);
        System.out.println(todayHijri); 
    }
}
```

This seems strange, considering that I have downloaded the latest joda time jar file from the official Joda Time release history on GitHub: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/releases (`joda-time-2.10.10.jar`), added it to the lib folder in my project, and added the jar file to my build path, as you can see in the file hierarchy below:

[image]

Comment: Check the _Run configuration_ (also known as _launch configuration_) Make sure the JAR file is on the classpath (or module path).

Answer (score 1):

As @Abra stated, making sure the JAR file was on my run configuration in my classpath worked :D.